# C# Regex: Named Group Valid Characters?

Tags: c#, regex

What constitutes a valid group name?

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?<what-letters-can-go-here>pattern)");
```

Comment: it's a good question.  I'm assuming your question gears toward knowing if you have the ability to use characters other than letters and digits.  I'm curious to know why you want more than that?

Comment: I'm starting to think it's only word characters... `\w+`.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: I don't need more than that, but I'm trying to reverse a regex like Django does (given a regex, return something that matches it). So I'm using regexes to match regexes >.< It's awful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short Answer

The allowed characters are `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

## Long Answer

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression):

> *name* must not contain any punctuation characters and cannot begin with a number.

But that's not very specific, so let's look at the source code:

The [source code for the class System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexParser.cs) shows us that the allowed characters are essentially `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. To be really precise though, there is this comment in the method that is used to check if the character is valid for a capturing group name:

> ```
> internal static bool IsWordChar(char ch) {
>         // According to UTS#18 Unicode Regular Expressions (http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/)
>         // RL 1.4 Simple Word Boundaries  The class of <word_character> includes all Alphabetic
>         // values from the Unicode character database, from UnicodeData.txt [UData], plus the U+200C
>         // ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER and U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER.
>         return CharInClass(ch, WordClass) || ch == ZeroWidthJoiner || ch == ZeroWidthNonJoiner;
>     }
> ```

And if you want to test it out yourself, [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pbcz3E) confirms that there are many non-punctuation characters that are not allowed in the name of a capturing group:

Comment: "essentially `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`" is pretty far from the truth. `WordClass` is much larger than that, plus you've got the two zero-width chars. But your code does show that, so thank you! Finally a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4):

Anything matched by `\w` which is effectively `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Not confirmed however..

Comment: `\w` looks close but `-` (dash) is not matched by `\w` yet is a valid group name character.

Comment: @Ahmad, a `-` is not valid, it is used to define a balancing group.

Comment: @Paul yes it's for balance groups, but my point is that `new Regex(@"(?<A-A>\d+)")` won't throw an "Invalid group name" although that's not the actual group name (it's just "A"). Nonetheless, `\w` seems right. Attempting to follow that trail in Reflector is a headache :)

Comment: `\w` in .NET is more than ASCII alphanumerics. Have you tried Unicode letters/digits like ß or à?

Comment: @Tim those appear to be valid.

Comment: @AhmadMageed FYI `(?<A-A>.)` is still a balancing group construct. I believe that gets interpreted as pushing the match to group `A`, then popping the match from group `A`. This is useful in constructs like `(?<x>.)(?<y-x>.)(?<-y>.)`. Note that `(?<A->.)` and `(?<A--A>.)` throw invalid group name.