# Is there any way to have a literal "." in the name of a RegEx named capture group?

Tags: regex, go, regex-group, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm doing some RegEx, which will run inside the [OpenTelemetry Collector](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/) against log data, where I require named capture groups to pull out groups of data from the log.

I wanted to adhere to the [OpenTelemetry Semantic Conventions around processes](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/semconv/resource/process/#process). These Semantic Conventions though require the use of "." as a separator - for example "process.command", "process.executable.name" etc.

This is where I'm having difficulty... RegEx101 doesn't seem to like having a "." in a named capture group, which is a reliable tool in my own experience so I'm inclined to believe it.

Is there a way to allow this?

Example RegEx:

`^(?P<process.executable.name>[^\[\]]+)\[?(?P<process.pid>\d+)?\]?$`

Example with dots (not working):

[image: Dots Not Working]

Note that escaping the dots with a "\" doesn't work - already tried it.

To demonstrate the RegEx itself does actually work without the breaking dots, using underscores instead of dots:

[image: Underscores Working]

Comment: It seems like you're talking about the _name_ of the group, not within what's captured. It also seems like you're talking about Go. I don't know if there's a regex-level standard for what's a valid group name, but other languages ([JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Named_capturing_group), looks like [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4271602/3001761)) require it to be an _identifier_.

Comment: It probably depends very much on the regex engine, but with `.` as separator you will probably have problems in all of them. In Java e.g. no separators at all are allowed, others might allow `_`, but I think that's it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes this is just about the name of the capture groups not that actual patterns themselves - and yeah those links for JS & C# seem to verify what I'm seeing here

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the go code [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/regexp/syntax/parse.go;l=1263) :

```golang
// isValidCaptureName reports whether name
// is a valid capture name: [A-Za-z0-9_]+.
// PCRE limits names to 32 bytes.
// Python rejects names starting with digits.
// We don't enforce either of those.
```

So **dots are not allowed in capture names**.

But you can use something like `process_executable_name` for example.

Answer (score -1):

In the provided scenario you could use normal (numbered) captured groups, and let them correspond with an array of capture group names based on index.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    data := "xxxx-xxx[12345]"
    // removed capture group names from the regex
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(`^([^\[\]]+)\[?(\d+)?\]?$`)
    //                            └───╴1╶──┘   └╴2╶┘
    // and placed them in an array that matches based on index
    group_names := [3]string{"", "process.executable.name", "process.pid"}
    //                        0  └──────────╴1╶──────────┘  └────╴2╶────┘

    match := regex.FindStringSubmatch(data)
    if match == nil {
        fmt.Println("no match found")
        return
    }

    groups := make(map[string]string)
    for i, part := range match {
        // exclude the entire match from the groups map
        if i == 0 { continue }
        group_name := group_names[i]
        groups[group_name] = part
    }

    fmt.Println(groups)
    // output: map[process.executable.name:xxxx-xxx process.pid:12345]
}
```

This associates capture group 1 with `"process.executable.name"` and capture group 2 with `"process.pid"` based on index.

ps. I'm not a Go programmer, so if the code above can be written cleaner/simpler feel free to update this answer.